# How to center image when it's smaller than parent and put in top left corner when it's bigger?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I have small image (eg. 100x100) and it's parent is bigger (eg. 200x200) then I want the image to be centered both vertically and horizontally in the parent.

But when image is wider (eg. 300x100) than the parent (200x200) I want it to be placed on the left side of the parent and have a horizontal scrollbar to scroll and see the whole image.

When image is higher (eg. 100x300) than the parent I want it to be placed at the top of the parent and have vertical scrollbar to be able to see the whole image.

I know how to do this in Javascript but I need a CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, using Flexbox and its `justify-content`/`align-items` with `center` should do it, but it doesn't, as it will create an overflow at i.e. both top/bottom when the flex item is higher.

Src: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-center

---

A better approach, that will work properly cross browsers, would be auto margins, and a wrapper around the `img`.

The reason for the wrapper is simply that there is an inconsistent behavior cross browsers when it comes to an `img` being a flex item.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMyomK)

Stack snippet

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px red solid;
  overflow: auto;                 /*  changed so it only show scroll when needed  */
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;        /*  IE need this  */
}
.box > div {
  margin: auto;
}
.box > div > img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/800" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/800/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tom Thanks, and compared to the other answer (and your `transform: translate` version), this is the only one that actually work, so you might want to consider which to accept.

Comment: Do you see any problems with `transform: translate` version?

Comment: @Tom Yes, if you take a close look, the images being _cut off_. Here is a codepen with both mine above and the `transform` version, which show the issue more clear when they are being rendered side-by-side: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEVjyK

Comment: It does cut! Didn't spot that one! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You probably just want to always center the image and it will align how you would like on it's own.

```
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px red solid;
  overflow:scroll;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

The most important part here is this:

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
```

It's these three lines will make it so any thing inside the 'box' will be centered vertically and horizontally.

Then you can add `overflow:scroll;` to allow for the scrolling you want.

Working example:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px red solid;
  overflow:scroll;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/500" alt=""> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/200" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Seems it's what I want. But the bottom option doesn't have scrollbars in Firefox (works in Chrome and IE11). Maybe it would be better without flex?
I changed it a bit to be without flex and now it's perfect: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGpNpW

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works so much better without Javascript!

Comment: @Tom interesting fix for Firefox I will have to remember that one. Glad I was able to help!

Comment: @Tom If you take a look at that codepen sample you see it overflow both at top/bottom (or left/right in the 3rd) and _cut off_ the image. I posted an answer explaining how to do that so it doesn't